# Word Counter React - Display Word Frequency

Tags: reactjs, list, tags, counter, frequency

Hi I'm fairly new to React and currently trying to write a word counter. The idea is that once you type in the text box it will then display a list of all the words and the frequency of how often they're used (This would be displayed in the span tag where it says wordCounts). The issue I'm currently having is it only displays one word with the frequency when I want a list. Moreover I honestly feel like could be achieved in a completely different way but again I'm fairly new to React and learning as I go.

If I need to share any more info or more code, please let me know.

React Code

```
import { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstValue: "",
      numberOfCharacters: "",
      withoutWhiteSpace: "",
      numberOfWords: "",
      linesCount: "",
      wordSelectionCount: "",
    };
  }

  firstHandle = (event) => {
    var input = event.target.value;

    const text = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
    const linesCount = text.split("/\r|\r\n|\n/").length;

    const numberOfCharacters = input === "" ? 0 : input.split("").length;
    const withoutWhiteSpace =
      input === "" ? 0 : input.split("").filter((char) => char !== " ").length;
    const words =
      input === "" ? 0 : input.split(" ").filter((word) => word.trim()).length;
    const lines = input === "" ? 1 : input.split(/\n/g).length;

    this.setState({
      firstValue: input,
      numberOfCharacters: numberOfCharacters,
      withoutWhiteSpace: withoutWhiteSpace,
      numberOfWords: words,
      linesCount: lines,
      wordSelectionCount: "",
    });
  };

  // This function is responsible for the word counting

  wordCounter = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var keys = [];
    var counts = {};
    const input = this.state.firstValue
      .replace(/\W/g, " ")
      .replace(/[0-9]/g, " ")
      .split(" ")
      .filter((word) => word.trim());
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      var word = input[i];
      if (counts[word] === undefined) {
        counts[word] = 1;
        keys.push(word);
      } else {
        counts[word] += 1;
        keys.push(word);
        // console.log(keys);
      }
      keys.sort();

      for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var key = keys[i];
        var result = key + " - " + counts[key];
        console.log(result);
      }
      this.setState({
        wordSelectionCount: result,
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    var numberOfCharacters = this.state.numberOfCharacters;
    var withoutWhiteSpace = this.state.withoutWhiteSpace;
    var words = this.state.numberOfWords;
    var lines = this.state.linesCount;
    var wordCounts = this.state.wordSelectionCount;
    console.log(wordCounts);

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <form>
            <h1>Character Counter</h1>
            <p>
              Characters <span>{numberOfCharacters}</span> Without White Space{" "}
              <span>{withoutWhiteSpace}</span> Words <span>{words}</span> Lines{" "}
              <span>{lines}</span>
            </p>
            <textarea
              id="textarea"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Please type some text..."
              value={this.firstValue}
              onChange={this.firstHandle}
            />
            <h1>Word Counting</h1>
            {/* This button calls the wordCounter Method which should display all the Word listings */}
            <button className="btn" onClick={this.wordCounter}>
              Words Count
            </button>
            <p>
              <span>{wordCounts}</span>
            </p>
          </form>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue

The issue is you are not iterating over `wordSelectionCount` to render your data, therefore your latest value will be displayed.

You can iterate over `wordSelectionCount` to render all of the data. But, I have a suggestion for you

### Suggestion

First suggestion will be, use functional components and react hooks.
Second, use the power of the object's [key-value] pair to store the word counts.

I have created a [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-khayyam-3y00p?file=/src/WordCounter.js) if you want to have a look. You can start adding words to see the word counter.

### Solution for the existing code

instead of rendering `<span>{wordCounts}</span>` directly, you should iterate over it. Such as:

```
this.state.wordSelectionCount && Object.keys(this.state.wordSelectionCount).map(word => (
 <span>{word} - {this.state.wordSelectionCount[word]}</span>
)}
```